# Notification JS, se puede personalizar?

Tags: javascript, html5, notification

He seguido estos pasos para hacer una notificación en mi web:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Usando_la_API_de_Notificaciones

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Notification

Y esto es lo que tengo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    theBody = "" +
            "<div style='background: #0055a0; color: #ffffff'>" +
            "   <strong>Tienes nuevos pedidos!</strong>"+
            "</div>";
    theTitle = "<h1>Hay un nuevo pedido</h1>";
    var options = {
        body: theBody,
    };
    var n = new Notification(theTitle,options);
    setTimeout(n.close.bind(n), 15000);
});
```

Y funciona, pero me muestra el contendio como texto plano, hay alguna manera de personalizar los colores el color de fondo y de la letra?

Comment: Puedes utilizar swalalert para darle mejor estilo

Comment: Sirve para mostrar notificaciones mientras la ventana está minimizada?, Además preferiría no tener que instalar más librerias JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes agregarle una imagen agregando

```
icon:
 "rutadelaimagen"
```

quedando asi:

```js
   
   Notification.requestPermission(function (status) {
        // Si el usuario acepta
        if (status === "granted") {
         var title = 'My Notification';
    var options = {
       icon: 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/superhero/400/superman.png',
       body: 'nueva notificación'
    };
  var n = new Notification(title,options);
    setTimeout(n.close.bind(n), 1000);
        }

});
```

Pero estás notificaciones no permiten muchas más personalización ya que el browser, Chrome , Mozilla,  Edge son las que le dan personalización propia